# set focus on the first textbox on the page with ajax editor in .net

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I a have a web form with few textboxes,dropdowns and finally towards the end of the page is 4 custom ajax editors. So on page load the focus is always inside the last editor and no way it comes to the first text box or top of page.On each page load the cursor goes inside the last editor control.How to bring the focus inside the first text box?
Below are the few methods i tried

`1.<body onload="document.body.scrollTop = 0;">`

```
2.    void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SetFocus(txtReqtitle);


}
```

for the above while loading the page i could see the focus goes to the desired text box and then it comes to the last custom control.

```
3.    if(!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("scrFocus"))
           {
              string strScript="var txtBox=document.getElementById('" + txtReqtitle.ClientID.ToString() +"');txtBox.focus();";
               ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"scrFocus", strScript,true);


            }
```

4.

```
function setFocus() {
document.getElementById("txtReqtitle").focus();
```

}

```
5. ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).SetFocus(txtReqtitle);
```

Any ideas? Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution which worked for me .would like to share it .. its simple ..just make the autofocus=false for the control.

Answer (score 0):

Seems focus property is not working in load event because of ajax editors

Please add txtReqtitle.Focus() in Page Prerendercomplete() event and let me know whether it works

Comment: Thanks Girish for the response. I got this message "SetFocus can only be called before and during PreRender."

Answer (score -1):

using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#<%= txtReqtitle.ClientID %>').focus();
});
```